# How can I create a 3D scatterplot with subcolumns?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, r-plotly

I'm looking to create a 3D scatterplot for a data structure like this:

```
            Criteria 1  Criteria 2  Criteria 3
Criteria 4  a           b           x,y
Criteria 5  a           b           x,y
```

where `a`, `b`, and `x, y` are seperate data points.

Note that `x, y` = 2 different data points.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not reproducible. That's not an unambiguous description of a data object. See the SO question; "How to make a great reproducible example in R"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example